# How to get UTC date of a date?

Tags: java, date, time, utc

Below is a Java POJO in my application:

```
public class Appointment {

    private Date appointmentStartDatetime;

    private String timezone;

    //...
}
```

Example values for these 2 properties are:

```
2021-10-06 05:30:00
"America/New_York"
```

`appointmentStartDatetime` represents the appointment start time in its declared timezone - i.e. the appointment starts at 5.30 in New York.

I want to convert this to a UTC date.

Is the below correct in order to do so?

```
 public static Date dateToUTC(Date date, String timezoneId){

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneId);
        calendar.setTimeZone(timeZone);

        return new Date(date.getTime() - calendar.getTimeZone().getOffset(date.getTime()));
    }
```

The method would be called as follows:

```
Date utcDate = dateToUTC(appointment.getEventStartDatetime(),appointment.getTimezone())
```

Comment: No my question is a bit more specific than that regarding the timezone property etc. thanks

Comment: You have misunderstood the meaning of `java.util.Date`. It is always related to UTC-offset that means its method `getTime()`refers to UTC. Your method `dateToUTC(…)` changes the value of `Date`-input by subtraction of an offset which is NOT okay. Just leave your `Date`-variable unchanged. Maybe you think of the output of `Date.toString()` whose dependency on local time zone confuses you.

Comment: why would I leave my date variable unchanged? I want the output date to be in UTC, and curerntly it represents a time in a specific timezone

Comment: Still misunderstanding. `java.util.Date` is always UTC nothing else if you consider its millis-since-1970-value. No need to change it. And this value is independent from time zone. You need the zone only for the local representation in terms of year-month-day-hour-minute. The new (and better) `java.time`-API defines new types for this purpose, for example `LocalDateTime` which can be inferred from an instant using a time zone..

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly and confusingly designed and long outdated. It seems that you have also let yourself confuse by them since, as has been said, your post and comments contain some misunderstandings. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Note that "2021-10-06 05:30:00" isn't a useful description of a `java.util.Date` value. As I mentioned in one of your earlier questions, identifying the exact instant (potentially by calling `getTime()` and reporting the millisecond value returned) is a much better approach to avoid any confusion.

Comment: In terms of understanding `java.util.Date` correctly, I have a blog post you might find useful: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

To avoid confusion use `ZonedDateTime` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time with time zone.

```
public class Appointment {

    private ZonedDateTime appointmentStartDateTime;
    
    // Constructor, etc.

    public Instant getUtcDateTime() {
        return appointmentStartDateTime.toInstant();
    }
    
}
```

Try it out:

```
        Appointment myAppointment = new Appointment(
                ZonedDateTime.of(2021, 1, 10, 5, 30, 0, 0,
                        ZoneId.of("America/New_York")));
        
        System.out.println(myAppointment.getUtcDateTime());
```

Output is:

> 2021-01-10T10:30:00Z

A `ZonedDateTime` is a date and time in a time zone. So you need only this one field instead of the two you had, `appointmentStartDatetime` and `timezone`. An `Instant` is a point in time independent of time zone. It prints in UTC, denoted by the trailing `Z` of the output above. And the conversion from `ZonedDateTime` to `Instant` is a matter of a simple method call.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: This answer guides you in the right direction. After going through this answer, I can say that even though my answer has some added features, this answer is just sufficient for your basic requirements.

Comment: @LiveandLetLive Thank you for the reading guide, I believe it’s helpful. And thanks for posting your answer, there’s a *wealth* of good information in it.

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the date-time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` and obtain the formatted string from it.

Note that the date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**Using the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

class Appointment {
    private LocalDateTime appointmentStartDatetime;
    private String timezone;

    public Appointment(LocalDateTime appointmentStartDatetime, String timezone) {
        this.appointmentStartDatetime = appointmentStartDatetime;
        this.timezone = timezone;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getAppointmentInLocalDateTime() {
        return appointmentStartDatetime;
    }

    public Instant getAppointmentInUTC() {
        return appointmentStartDatetime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    }

    public ZonedDateTime getAppointmentInZonedDateTime() {
        return appointmentStartDatetime.atZone(ZoneId.of(timezone));
    }

    public ZonedDateTime getAppointmentInZdtAnotherTimeZone(String timezone) {
        return getAppointmentInZonedDateTime().withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(timezone));
    }
    // ...
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Appointment appointment = new Appointment(
                LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2020, Month.FEBRUARY, 15), LocalTime.of(10, 30)), "America/New_York");

        System.out.println(appointment.getAppointmentInLocalDateTime());
        System.out.println(appointment.getAppointmentInUTC());
        System.out.println(appointment.getAppointmentInZonedDateTime());
        System.out.println(appointment.getAppointmentInZdtAnotherTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-02-15T10:30
2020-02-15T10:30:00Z
2020-02-15T10:30-05:00[America/New_York]
2020-02-15T21:00+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]
```

1. An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the time-line.
2. A [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) holds state equivalent to three separate objects, a `LocalDateTime`, a `ZoneId` and the resolved `ZoneOffset`. The function, [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-) returns a copy of this date-time with a different time-zone, retaining the instant.

Given below is an [overview of the Java SE 8 date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html):

[image]

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.